# embedding image using DomPDF [Laravel9]

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I'm studying Laravel and DomPDF. I've been helped by stackoverflow people and getting unserstand Laravel. now I'm having problem to embed image in PDF.
I searched that I need to use base64_encode for image display so I wrote this.

Controller

```
public function generate_pdf(Student $student)
{
    $main_image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($student->student_image));

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', compact('student')->with('main_image', $main_image));

    return $pdf->download('download.pdf');
}
```

myPDF.blade.php

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $main_image }}">
```

Data store and view show blade file works fine.
And This is When user store the data 'store' function's image save path in controller.

Contoller

```
$file_name = 'main_photo' . $ja_time . '.' . request()->student_image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        request()->student_image->move(public_path('images'), $file_name);
```

show.blade.php

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/' . $student->student_image) }}" width="200"
                                        class="img-thumbnail" />
```

Could someone teach me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put student_image in public_path('images'), it should be:

```
public function generate_pdf(Student $student)
{
    $main_image = base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path('images/' . $student->student_image)));

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', compact('student', 'main_image'));

    return $pdf->download('download.pdf');
}
```

in myPDF.blade.php:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $main_image }}">
```

Comment: Dear @Khang Tran Thank you so much for helping me. I tried your code. so I can see the PDF file but image won't show up. white cross box appear and it say  Image not found or type unknown.  so I wrote like this <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $main_image) }}" width="200" class="img-thumbnail" /> but now PDF generate won't start.

Comment: I edited my answer, your original code in myPDF.blade.php is right, <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $main_image }}">

Comment: Dear @Khang Tran Thank you very much! You helped me twice. I really appreciate. This is perfect. Thank you!